# Rails 3: Filling a form/database field automatically based on current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a **posts** model in my rails app that has a form/database field for a **sender** that I want to automatically fill with the **current_user** as generated by Authlogic. Basically I want to keep track of the person who created/sent the "post" and not allow them to change that field.

I tried using the following trick from another StackOverflow question below which works as long as there is a field in the form.

```
def new
   @post = Post.new :sender => current_user.username

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
     format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
   end
end
```

What I'm looking for is a way to auto-fill that value in the database, hidden from the user, and not requiring a form entry.

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

~Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should set up a model relation between the two, or that is what you have already.

in your create method just do this

```
@post = current_user.posts.create(params[:post])
```

This requires no field in the front end and enforces the relation between the user and their posts

EDIT on comments

Sounds like you need to change in post.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

to

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
```

EDIT to the schema

According to your model you're just storing a string of the sender/receiver, since that is the case what you need to do is this:

```
in controller#create
@post = Post.create(params[:post])
@post.sender = current_user.username
```

**EDIT: How to do this properly**

Based on your comment it looks like you want to do this in a relational way, good.

First of all for your post you will need to change sender and receiver into integers and rename then sender_id and receiver_id respectively.

Next in your user.rb model you'll need to have the following:

```
has_many :sent_posts, :foreign_key => "sender_id"
has_many :received_posts, :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

In your post.rb model you will need to have the following:

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User"
```

Now you can do the following when creating a post

```
@post = current_user.sent_posts.create(params[:post])
```

And the following methods are available

```
@post.sender                #=> gets the sender
@post.receiver              #=> gets the receiver
current_user.sent_posts     #=> all posts from this user
current_user.received_posts #=> all posts for this user
```

**NOTE** I'm not able to verify this but I'm sure the above should work for you, there may be some slight errors as I can't double check currently

Comment: I might need to ask this in another question, but now I get an "undefined method `user_id=' for #<Post:0x3c06180>" error. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: My "post.rb" model has the "belongs_to :user" relation and my "user.rb" model has "has_many :posts" relation if that helps.

Comment: What is the schema for your post model?

Comment: You need to have a sender_id and receiver_id in there somewhere if you want to have object relations between posts and users so you could do things like `post.sender` and `post.receiver`. If you're just trying to store strings that is fine though, I'll update my answer according to your model

Comment: I know I'm asking a lot of questions, but is there a better way to setup the posts and uses relationally? I definitely want to store user_id's in the "sender" and "receiver" fields and have a relational model between such that a user can see all his interactions (for example, if the user is Jeff he can see all interactions he was part of) and can even list interactions between 2 users (i.e. show all "Jeff and Steve" interactions). I'm defintely a Rails Noob, so if I'm designing my app in a shoddy or dangerous way i would appreciate any feedback! Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Updated for a better approach that should help you out more

Answer (score 0):

You could always have the model before_create add the value for that one field along with the params.. That would make sure the value is added just before the create statement gets executed..

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. why not do that in the `create` action:

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(params[:post].merge({:sender => current_user.username}))
end
```

Comment: This gives a "undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass" error FYI. ~Dan